# What is the meaning of this inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am a bit confused about this, I am reading a math  textbook and it says something that I dont agree with. Maybe I am missing something,If $-1<y-5<1$, does this necessarilly mean that
(i)$y>4$  or (ii)$y<6$ . In my understanding, the given inequality implies that $4<y<6$ and this does not necessarily mean $y>4$. for example, 8>4 but 8 does not lie between 4 and 6. I have the same argument about y<6.

Comment: $4 < y < 6$ means $y > 4$ ***and*** $y < 6$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but that does not answer my question. if _1<y-5<1, does this necessarily mean that y>4?

Comment: I think it did answer your question, but that's a moot point as you have accepted an answer that ways the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means both conditions have to be satisfied. You can't choose y=8 because it violates the condition that y has to be less than 6

Answer (score 0):

For two sets $A,B$ the statement

"$x\in A$ necessarily means $x\in B$"

is equivalent to the statement  "$A\subset B$".

This **does not** mean: "the region defined by the condition $ -1 < y-5 < 1$  and the region defined by the condition $y> 4$ are the same.".